# How to sanitize JSON string on deserialization to ObjectNode using Jackson

Tags: java, json, security, jackson, deserialization

I have a JSON string from response to REST API which I am trying to deserialize into an ObjectNode in Jackson like below.

```
String response = webservice(...);
ObjectNode jsonObj = new ObjectMapper().readTree(response);
```

In our static scan of the source code, it found vulnerability to JSON injection that this call could allow an attacker to inject arbitrary elements or attributes into the JSON entity.

How can I make sure to protect against JSON injection?

Comment: Map it to an actual Entitiy rather than generic ObjectNodes with Jackson and don't ignore unknown properties?

Comment: Could you please explain how mapping to a concrete object would prevent  JSON injection? Let's say through JSON injection, an attacker tries to override or set a property on this object.